# Is it possible to change an images size independent from an imageview's size?

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, imageview

Is it possible to change an imageview's size after initializing but keep the size the image has after initiliazing? Or is there maybe a way to change an image's size without changing the imageview.

**Edit:** I need to be able to crop the image from bottom to top without affecting the size of the imageview, so that the bottom part of the image is cut off.

Comment: explain what you need specificly

Answer (score 0):

You mist likely looking for `android:scaleType` of ImageView. [See docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:scaleType).

Comment: I looked into this, but the only crop that is available is center and I need something that crops to the top, after using scaletype="FitXY".